# Simplest way to run a vim script

Tags: vim

What is the simplest way to run a vim function/script? For example, to run a python script I'll usually open two windows, the script on top and the shell on bottom:

```
# script.py
def hello():
    print ('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()

-----------------------

$ python script.py
```

I assume to run a vim script I would want to be 'inside' the vim process (so for example, I could highlight text or do whatever might be necessary for the input to the vim script). Currently I do this in a quite tedious manner: I put the function in `vimrc` and then whenever I want to run it I do something like:

- Re-save file - `:w`
- Re-source vimrc - `:so $MYVIMRC`
- Re-run function - `:call MyFunction()`

I was hoping I could just create a file called something like `script.vim` (in any directory), open the file and then 'run it'. What would be the best way to do this? For reference, here is the function I want to run

```
function MyFunction()
    echom "Hello"
    echom getline('.')
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:so %` to source the file, which will run any commands in it. For example:

```
function MyFunction()
    echom "Hello"
    echom getline('.')
endfunction

call MyFunction()
```

Now running:

```
:w | so%
```

Will print at the bottom:

```
Hello
call MyFunction() <-- current line the current is on
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```